# Declared variable gives a different output once program is executed

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    float x =5400.768;

    printf("%f", x);

}
```

In the above code, once I execute the program it will display 5400.768066 as output with 3 extra decimal places. Why is that?

Comment: This is because of the way floating point numbers are stored in memory. Unlike integers, floats are not precisely stored in memory; instead an exponent and mantissa is stored. http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm

Comment: @AiSER_HD, adding 4 spaces in front of your code will make it display as code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is [floating point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples). Basically, the number is stored in 32 bits, which can only contain a finite amount of precision, and usually only have ~7 decimal digits of precision. If you need more accuracy you could use a 64-bit value (aka `double`).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=f4ekifyijIg if you wanna know how `floats` are stored in memory.

If you want to print just to 3 decimal places, use `printf("%.3f",variable_name);`.